# Why does the rowspan attribute not work in the Matt-Esch/virtual-dom library?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the Matt-Esch **[virtual-dom](https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom)** library.

I need to create a table with a `rowspan`, like this ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Le5gyzxy/)):

```
<a href="google.co.uk">Link</a>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>Foo</td>
        <td>Baz</td>
        <td>Baz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Baz</td>
        <td>Baz</td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

But when I try it with virtual-dom, the `rowspan` attribute is ignored ([requirebin](http://requirebin.com/?gist=23f88375e868910409a1)):

```
var h = require('virtual-dom/h');
var createElement = require('virtual-dom/create-element');

function draw()  {
    return h('div', [
      h('a', {href: 'google.co.uk'}, 'link'),
      h('table', [
            h('tr', [
                h('td', {rowspan: '2'}, 'Foo'),
                h('td', 'Baz'),
                h('td', 'Baz')
            ]),
            h('tr', [
                h('td', 'Baz'),
                h('td', 'Baz')
            ]),
        ]),
    ])
}

var tree = draw();              
var rootNode = createElement(tree);
document.body.appendChild(rootNode);
```

I notice the `href` attribute for the link works as expected, but the  `rowspan` attribute on the  `td` does not.

Why does the rowspan attribute not work in the Matt-Esch/virtual-dom library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

virtual-dom deals in JavaScript DOM properties, not HTML attributes.

JavaScript DOM properties are case sensitive and the HTML `rowspan` attribute maps on to [the `rowSpan` (with a capital S) property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-48237625).